# How to display/insert an image on an option html tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to insert some code in WooCommerce wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options function.
I got line like this:

```
$html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name, $term, $attribute, $product ) ) . '</option>';
```

and I need to insert this code:

```
'<img src="' . esc_attr($variation['image']['thumb_src']) . '">' .
```

if I just insert it like that - nothing shows, but when I display it inside esc_html, the code is shown as plain text and I see it configured correctly.

How do I need to insert code here to display image?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it's showing the image.

```
function woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html( $html, $args ) {
    $variation['image']['thumb_src'] = "https://i.picsum.photos/id/230/50/50.jpg";
    $html = '<img src="' . esc_attr($variation['image']['thumb_src']) . '">';
    $html.= '<img src="' . esc_attr($variation['image']['thumb_src']) . '">';
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 10, 2 );
```

[image]

Comment: as I mentioned in previous comment, it don't work with multiple $html elements, for example, if I need to do foreach

Comment: @justsimpleuser Updated the answer and it's showing 2 images

Comment: great, it showing multiple images. But now to get variation selection functionality I need to write here code by myself?

Comment: @justsimpleuser Yes, if you are changing it like this, you have to do it by yourself